# how to find out which column MySQL error relates to in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I can get MySQL errors with `mysqli_error()` function in php, but I don't want to show user the error that MySQL has been sent. I want to get the name of the field or column that the error relates to it and tell user that your input in 'example' field should be changed. I know that I can use a function like `strpos()` in PHP to check whether the error expression contains the names of the columns or not, but as you know some of the MySQL error expressions contain names of all the columns in table and here I can't decide next to which input field show error?
is there a function like for example `mysqli_error_column()` to get the name of the column throws the error? or any other advises?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO customers (password, active, email, active_code, submit_date)VALUES('$codedPass', '0', '$email', '$verificationKey', '$currDate')";
        $insertResult = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

        if(!$insertResult) {
            $queryError = mysqli_error($conn);
            if(preg_match("/\b"."email"."\b/",$queryError)) {
                $php_input_error['email'] = $error_msg['unknown'];
            }
            else if(preg_match("/\b"."password"."\b/",$queryError)) {
                $php_input_error['pass'] = $error_msg['unknown'];
            }
            else $php_input_error['general'] = "there's an error with your inputs, please check them again.";
        }
```

Comment: You should really validate the user input before you try to insert it into the database. You should also use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating the SQL-string, since it removes the risk of [SQL injection attacks](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: I have validated user inputs in earlier lines, and this piece of code is almost the end of the code and here I insert the validated and trimmed user inputted data to the db. Here I try to get any unexpected errors that may occur during insert process.

Comment: If you still get specific errors on specific columns after your validation, then it's your validation that needs to be changed, not the DB-part (except from the things i mentioned in my first comment).

Comment: I don't get any error and I validation rules work very well and I easily can insert my rows into the db without any error, but I have written this piece for when something occurs and I haven't predicted it already.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that there is some other way to do that.

However I would advise you completely different solution: 
it will be nice to validate data BEFORE sending it to DB (in PHP code).

In such case:

1. You may implement validation rules of any complexity (length,
   allowed symbols, data ordering, validation dependencies between
   fields, etc).
2. You will know everything about an error. So you may show more understandable message to user.
3. You will decrease load of database server.

Comment: I have validated user inputs in earlier lines, and this piece of code is almost the end of the code and here I insert the validated and trimmed user inputted data to the db. Here I try to get any unexpected errors that may occur during insert process.